# creating a class to store some integers Java

Tags: java

I have a datafile, which I am trying to read and store its values,
The file looks something like this

```
  Mammal    fat_content(%)  protein_content(%)
  Bison          7.9           5.9
  Guinea_pig     3.9           8.1
  Dolphin        14.0          10.4
  Donkey          1.4          1.7
```

The thing I am trying to do is to make a class which will store the doubles, 
I have a scanner object in my main class like

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

String elementInfo=scan.nextLine(); //It will have the first line which is  Mammal  fat_content(%)        protein_content(%)

Scanner elemInfo=new Scanner(elementInfo); //Scanner to parse the elementInfo

String kindOfElement=elementInfo.next(); // It will give the mammal

String [] varNames=new String[numOfVariables];  
for(int i=0;i<numOfVariables;i++){     //I have made the for loop for this because there could be more variable values like fat_content and protein_content,.....,weight
        varNames[i]=elemInf.next();

    }
```

This code is just storing the names of the variables,but I want to make a class which will store a number of doubles for example fat_content would have its values stored in an array....
I am sorry if I am not making any sense, all I want is that to store all values of fat_content in an array with the help of a new class.....Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeena

Answer (score 0):

You just need a conversion between String to Double.

This:

```
String [] varNames=new String[numOfVariables];

varNames[i]=elemInf.next();
```

Should be:

```
double[] varNames = new double[numOfVariables];

varNames[i] = elemInf.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `List` for this case. Mainly something like:

```
List<Double> fat_content = new ArrayList<Double>();    
fat_content.add(elemInf.nextDouble());
```

Or

```
varNames[i] = elemInf.nextDouble();
```

`Scanner` has an added advantage of giving separated tokens according to type. (ref. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29))